# Saving Multiple Data - Firebase Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to set multiple values into my firebase database. Every new data i set replaces the old data instead of adding up. Just like how users comment. Users are able to add up as many comments they would like. But mine, a new comment would replace an old comment already in the DB.  To keep my code short, i would post where the breakpoints.
I thought array could do the trick. What am i missing please?

**Model**

```
 internal class MessageContent
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }

        public MessageContent()
        {

        }

        public MessageContent(string Email, string Message){

            this.Email = Email;
            this.Message = Message;
            Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMMMM dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
```

**Saving Comments to Firebase**

```
 private void PostComments()
            {
                MessageContent save = new MessageContent();
                save.Message = edtChat.Text;

                mLike.Child(post_key).Child(mAuth.CurrentUser.Uid).SetValue(save.Message);
                edtChat.Text = "";

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens if the path is the same when you set the value. 'Post_key' must get a new value each time. Otherwise it will replace the old value.

That is how I see it. I'm not 100% sure though. Hope that helps.

Ps. You can always test with hardcoded values for 'post_key' to check if it overwrites or not. :-)

Comment: With what i am doing now, i would need the post key to be the same (for user comments)

Comment: I am pretty sure that you need to have an unique id somewhere. Either before the postkey or after the userID. Otherwise you will always overwrite. That is how firebase works.